# How do I set font size default for the TeXShop editing window?

Tags: editors, texshop

I edit several .tex documents I'm working on in TeXShop and every time I open them, I see Helvetica 12. Even with reading glasses it's hard for me to see so I select all, type Command-K, and set the font size to 18. I've tried TeXShop preferences "Set" but all it does is show me a sample of the font. The .pdf windows are just fine but

How do I set the default font in the .tex editing window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Source tab of TeXShop->Preferences.

Comment: It should also open the Font Chooser. If it doesn’t try the Source->Font->Open Fonts menu item while that sample sheet is open.

Comment: Thanks. I selected the text in. the. window,  hit Command-K and set the font to 18 pt.